# Word Template - Sections - Bringing those sections in a WinForms app

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm not all the familiar with Word Templates, but I'm wondering if there is a way to name your sections from within your Word template...

For example:

- Section A
- Section B
- Section C
- Section D
- Section E

In each of those sections there would be text inside of them.

In the Win Form application I would like to display those Section Names in a control where the user can select 1 or more of those sections which would then auto-create a new word document.

Is this possible?  If so what do I research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a list of the Sections present in a Word Template,
but these Sections have no name.
You could only use an Index to extract them from their collection.

Assuming you have an active Document called wDoc you could loop on every section in this way

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...

foreach (Section section in wDoc.Sections) 
{
  ....
}
```

Look at [the Section Interface on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms264604.aspx)